# Amazon MWS Request Report API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I used Amazon MWS Request Report API to request report but the response returned from API is

## Service Response

```
    GetReportRequestListResponse
        GetReportRequestListResult
            NextToken
                string
            HasNext

            ReportRequestInfo
                ReportRequestId
                    string
                ReportType
                    string
                StartDate
```

in above results there is no values only the value types are there I download client library from https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/reports/v20090101/php.html/187-0944446-1656165

Here is the code that I am using to call it:

```
$serviceUrl = "mws.amazonservices.com";; 

$config = array(
    'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl, 
    'ProxyHost' => null, 
    'ProxyPort' => -1, 
    'MaxErrorRetry' => 3, 
); 

$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array(MARKETPLACE_ID)); 
$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_RequestReportRequest(); 
$request->setMarketplaceIdList($marketplaceIdArray); 
$request->setMerchant(MERCHANT_ID); 
$request->setReportType('GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA'); 
$request->setReportOptions('ShowSalesChannel=true'); 
$requestReportArray = invokeRequestReport($service, $request);
```

any ideas?

Comment: Could you add the PHP code that you are using to call the service to your question?